# Escaping characters when passing arguments to a command

Tags: bash, android

I regularly record audio files using my Android phone to WAV files to the internal storage of my phone. I'd like to write a Bash script to pull the most recent recorded file from my phone and move it to my Desktop. Here's what I've got so far:

```
adb shell find /storage/sdcard0/Sound\ Recordings/ | tail -1 | while read file ; do
    adb pull "$file" ~/Desktop/
done
```

However, this fails. It seems that ADB doesn't properly escape things and I get the following messages when trying to run the script:

```
' does not existstorage/sdcard0/Sound Recordings/20120817T065953.wav
```

It seems to ignore the double quotes and everything basically breaks when it tries to run, as it presumably sees 3 arguments rather than two, something like this:

```
adb pull /storage/sdcard0/Sound Recordings/20120817T065953.wav ~/Desktop/
```

How can I adjust my script to insert backslashes into my `$file` variable where necessary? Is that the proper solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running this in another shell level, it gets expanded *before* it's run in the subshell. The easiest way to fix this is to escape any special characters in the file name:

```
adb shell find /storage/sdcard0/Sound\ Recordings/ | tail -1 | while IFS= read -r file ; do
    adb pull "$(printf %q "$file")" ~/Desktop/
done
```

Comment: This is now giving me the following error: `remote object '/storage/sdcard0/Sound$'Recordings/20120831T070055.wav\r'' does not exist`. Somehow, it's formatting the filename in a very strange way.

Comment: `$file` needs to be quoted in the printf command. Also, change `while read file` to `while IFS= read -r file` to read the whole line. Or better, just do: `file=$(adb shell find /blah | tail -1); adb pull "$(printf %q "$file")"`.

Comment: @dubiousjim Good tips. I'd normally include them in the first revision, except that it's pretty much in the middle of a spectrum of robustness for [file loops](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
adb pull "/storage/sdcard0/Sound Recordings/$(
    adb shell ls -1t '/storage/sdcard0/Sound Recordings' |
        sed q |
        tr -d '\r'
)" .
```

You are facing problems because `adb` return some carriage returns like Windows `\r`

`sed q` is just a funny way to display the first occurrence like `head -n1`

Comment: Have you tested ?